# DB2 load command inserts the date values in wrong format

Tags: bash, unix, db2

below is my load command which inserts the data related to sales into db2 table

```
LOAD FROM /scripts/Ojob/data.txt OF DEL
MODIFIED BY COLDELX09
METHOD P (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
MESSAGES /logs/Ojob/Load_Messages.txt
INSERT INTO SALES (SALEDATE, SSECTION, POSTCODE, ORDERS, SALES, 
SHIP, NUMBER)
NONRECOVERABLE INDEXING MODE AUTOSELECT;
```

below is the sample data where the date column is in the format (dd/mm/yyyy)

```
  07/08/2017    4   TN29 0  1   119.94  0.00    111
  07/08/2017    715 BN3 7   1   0.00    8.95    222
  07/08/2017    715 CB9 7   1   47.00   8.95    333
```

the SALEDATE column is define as DATE type in the db2 table and it suppose to insert the date in the format YYYY-MM-DD , But for some weird reason it insert the date value in incorrect month

So the expected output of the above date value should be in 2017-08-07 
but when i query the db2 table it inserted the data into 2017-07-08 and it started happening recently and i really have no clue about why its doing like that, when i reload the file without any change the data is loaded into the correct date , Can anyone explain me why DB2 functioning like this ? , the load function is called from a shell script.

Comment: DB2 will display the date value according to your "application code page"/locale. So you need to describe how you perform the SELECT on the table to view the date values .  For example, if you connect to the database from the unix command-line and issue a SELECT then DB2 will display date values according to the value of your LANG environment variable.  If you query from Windows, DB2 will display according to DB2CODEPAGE setting (if present) or the system-default-locale of Windows, or the locale defined by the application used to submit the SELECT.

Comment: i am not seeing any issues in viewing the data in the tool or unix, the problem is when the data is inserted it inserts the data in wrong month where the db tool and unix command-line also reflects the same , but the same data inserts fine in the correct month in the next run without any changes.not sure why the date inserts in wrong month..it takes the mm/dd/yyyy value in the file to mm/dd/yyyy which is incorrect. Is there any profile in Unix/db2 where i can check why its incorrect in the first run ?

Comment: If it is a delimited file that you are importing (and not an IXF format file), then what is the date format in that file when it works, and when it 'fails' ?  If the date format is not 'yyyy-mm-dd' then expect some issues if your locale is not set to match.  Prove this with a test table, and test data, and change the date-values until you see how it works.

Comment: its a tab delimited file and the date format is in DD/MM/YYYY , 07/08/2017. it fails when the load command loads the file for the first time it reads it incorrectly and inserts it 07 as month and 08 as DD, it works when i retry the load without any changes in the file

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a modifier on your LOAD command, like `modified by dateformat="DD/MM/YYYY"`  to tell DB2 the date format in your delimited files?  You would have to make certain that the date format was always correct.

Comment: Yes, i tried the above step in the load command and received the below error , SQL3191N  The field in row "F1-1", column "1" which begins with "08/08/2017
748 NG25 0 1 35.00 " does not match the user specified DATEFORMAT, TIMEFORMAT,
or TIMESTAMPFORMAT. The row will be rejected.

Comment: Please ignore the above comment, i have modified the load command like modified by dateformat="DD/MM/YYYY" COLDELX09 and it now loads the data in correct format. But really dont have any clue about why the initial load inserted the data in wrong date.

Comment: The dateformat modifier works as long as you guarantee the format in the file matches it.   I believe it failed previously because the locale effective at the time mismatched the data.

Comment: You can avoid date-literal ambiguity issues, and avoid having to specify a dateformat modifier if you can arrange that the date literals in the data file are exactly YYYY-MM-DD (ISO 8601 format, because DB2 LUW defaults to that)